# How to register service-worker in rails 7 used importmap?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, import-maps

Updated on 1/18/2023 to reflect the answer from [Bijan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306478/bijan)

#### Facing problem

I want to convert a web application created with Rails 7 that uses importmap into a PWA.
However, I'm having trouble registering the service-worker using importmap.
I'd appreciate it if you could give me some advice.

#### Status quo

At first, I tried to use [this gem](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails), but it didn't work in the importmap environment, so I referred to [this site](https://onrails.blog/2021/03/02/rails-pwas-using-turbo-hhnpwa-7/), but it didn't work.

The result of lighthouse check is as below.

[image]

##### Development environment

ruby 3.1.3
rails 7.0.3
importmap-rails 1.1.2
tailwindcss-rails 2.0.10
Sprockets 4.1.1.

#### Related source code

`config/route.rb`

```rb
    get '/service_worker', to: 'service_workers#service_worker'
    get '/offline', to: 'service_workers#offline'
```

./app/controllers
├── `service_workers_controller.rb`

```rb
class ServiceWorkerController < ApplicationController
    protect_from_forgery except: :service_worker
    skip_before_action :require_login
    
    def service_worker; end
    
    def offline; end
end
```

./app/views/service_worker
├── offline.html.erb
└── `service-worker.html.erb`

```html
<script>
  const VERSION = 'v1';
  const NAME = 'app_name-';
  const CACHE_NAME = NAME + VERSION;
  const urlsToCache = [
      "./offline.html"
  ];
    
    
  self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
      event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
          console.log('Opened cache');
          return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
        })
      );
  });
    
  self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) 
      if (event.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && 
  event.request.mode !== 'same-origin')
          return;
      event.respondWith(
          cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
              if (response) {
                  return response;
              }
              return fetch(event.request);
          })
      );
  });
    
  self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
      event.waitUntil(
          cache.keys().then(keys => Promise.all(
              keys.map(key => {
                  if (!CACHE_NAME.includes(key)) {
                      return cache.delete(key);
                  }
              })
          )).then(() => {
              console.log(CACHE_NAME + "activated");
          })
      );
  });
</script>
```

/app/javascript/controllers
└── `service-worker_controller.js`

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
    
export default class extends Controller {
    connect () {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker", {scope: "/" }).then(function (registration) {
                console.log("ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ", registration.scope);
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("ServiceWorker registration failed: ", err);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

app/views/layouts/
└── `application.html.erb`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= csp_meta_tag %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
        <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    
        <title><%= page_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
        <%= render 'application/favicon' %>
        <%= display_meta_tags(default_meta_tags) %>
      </head>
    
      <body class="dark:bg-gray-800 break-words flex flex-col min-h-screen">
        <%= render 'static_pages/navbar' %>
        <div id="flash" class="z-50 flex-col fixed top-16 right-1 ">
          <%= render 'shared/flash' %>
        </div>
        <%= tag.main class: "mb-auto relative" do %>
          <div class="w-full" data-controller="service-worker">
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= render 'static_pages/footer' %>
      </body>
    </html>
```

#### Error message

when I reload the page, The following error appears on the console of chrome DV tool.
`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`
Also, the following message appears on chrome DV tool console.
[image]

Please let me know if you find anything strange.

Answer (score 0):

So far your example seems fine except the rendering of your service-worker.js file via the controller. Your controller complains that it didn’t find a template. You could create a view for the service_worker method and paste the content of your service-worker.js file inside. You could also make your controller method send the file down directly. Should be an easy fix.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer.
I intend to reflect what you pointed out (as above), but unfortunately I still can't install serviceworker successfully.
I would be grateful if you could let me know if there are any misunderstandings or if there are any strange points.

Answer (score 0):

that's not a template issue. The error is mentioned in the error message you posted. The script is returned as text/html when it should be javascript.

Your current code is shipping JS as text/html what is confusing for the browser which is then stopping the execution of the worker's code.

You need to mention in the header that the worker's code is application/javascript or something like that to make sure that the browser interpret it the proper way.